# How to get two textviews in a listview on the same line?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have two TextViews tvA and tvB which appear in a ListView lvA.
tvA and tvB display data pulled from a Sqlite Database using Cursor.

```
Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

    String[] from = new String[]
                    {DBAdapter.KEY_A,DBAdapter.KEY_B};
            int[] to = new int[]
                    {R.id.tvA,R.id.tvB};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.lvA, cursor,from,to);
 myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvA);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(myList);
```

The issue is that tvA and tvB doesn't appear as one item in lvA (i.e. they don't appear on the same line)  and appear as two different items.

Below is the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="5dip"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvA"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you need that both in same align ?

Comment: you need both textview in the same line as item of the listview?

Comment: yes i need tvA and tvB in the same align

Comment: Then you can use LinearLayout for that

Comment: tvA and tvB are themselves the items of lvA.I need them to be as one item.

Comment: even Linear Layout isn't of help.I tried Linear Layout with horizontal orietnation

Comment: are you using adapter ?

Comment: Yaah.SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: why can't you append the textview in tva of second result? @gambit

Comment: Then can you able to change that layout.

Comment: if tvA was long so tvB will go to next line.you can use linearLayout instead.I don't use simpleCursorAdapter so if your problem don't solve,use CursorAdapter(create custom adapter and extend CursorAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the TextViews in the same align then you can use LinearLayout with [android:layout_weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) attribute.

To have equal width TextView, give same weight value.

Comment: I tried that.Still tvA and tvB appear as two different items.I want them as a single item.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this :

Main Java:

```
  //DECLARE:

  private Map<String, Map<String, String>> mMenuView = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

//IN onCreateView

```
        Adapter mAdapter = new NewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mMenuView);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

// ADD onActivityCreated or onStart save data from your DB and store in mMenuView

```
      Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
      tempMap.put("TEXTVALE_A", datafromdb_A);
      tempMap.put("TEXTVALE_B", datafromdb_B);

      mMenuView.put(Integer.toString(mMenuView.size()), tempMap);

      }
```

//NEWADAPTER

private class NewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
    private Context mContext;
    private TextView mTitle1;
    private TextView mTitle2;

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> mData = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();


    public NewAdapter(Context applicationContext,Map<String, Map<String, String>> mMenuValue) {


        mContext = applicationContext;
        mData =  mMenuValue;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(Integer.toString(position));
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Map<String, String> data = mData.get(Integer.toString(position));
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linear_layout, null);

            mTitle1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1A);
            mTitle2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1B);

        }

        if (data != null) {

            mTitle1.setText(data.get("TEXTVALE_A"));
            mTitle2.setText(data.get("TEXTVALE_B"));
        }
        return convertView;

   }

}
```

linear_layout.xml

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/t1A"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color3x"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                >


                 <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/A"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                        />


            </LinearLayout>

          </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: create an new layout and update your SimpleCursorAdapter with new layout

Comment: Not Working!
tvB moves down as next item.

Comment: can you share your code :both listview -xml and java

Comment: Better you user HashMap for store data and user custom adapter rather than SimpleCursorAdapter

Answer (score 0):

You can use TableLayout

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
                    <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">            
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvA"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >   
                    </TextView>    
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvB"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    </TextView> 
                    </TableRow></TableLayout >
```

or LinearLayout with `android:orientation="horizontal"`
and TextView with `android:layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it with three items on the same row = This is my item list filled from a cursor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_StudentName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:maxWidth="75dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/student_id" 
    android:padding="5dp"></TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_StudentLocation"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:maxWidth="75dp" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/student_Location" 
    android:padding="5dp"></TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_StudentClass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:maxWidth="75dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/student_class" >
 </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

I'm in the process of replacing the hard sizes with info from the dimen file, but so far this has worked.